# OpenCart: Apply refund to sales order

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm looking for a way to apply a refund to a customer, without an extension.
To adjust inventory would too would be a bonus.

Best solution I've found was [OpenCart Forum](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=18348#p118656), by creating a product called 'refund' and either adding it to the invoice or creating a new order with just the refund amount.

It would seem to be a nice solution but is there a way to hide products in OpenCart 2?
Not assigning it to a group it is still visible from search.

Ideally OpenCart should have a refund or reversal option, to correct the sales total and inventory.
Since for accounting you can't just delete the order, there still needs to be a record of it.